# I have a problem with xAxisLabel of SwiftCharts by ivanschuetz

Tags: swift, swiftcharts

in swiftCharts library made by ivanschuetz i cannot have multiple value for one LineChartDataPoint object

LineChartDataPoint has something like this:

```
LineChartDataPoint(value: 23.0 , xAxisLabel: "A")
```

but i want it to get an array of value like this

```
LineChartDataPoint(value: [23.0, 10.0, 20.2, 33.6] , xAxisLabel: "A" )
```

How can i achieve this?